# Preventing Hidden Contents of each column When Exports from Datatables

Tags: jquery, excel, datatables

I am using JQuery Data table and having some hidden values in each column . When exporting to excel, its showing that hidden values too  each column .
is there any way to prevent this ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean that you have hidden columns or if you have hidden data in some of your columns? Assuming you have hidden columns:

DataTables has a built-in Excel `exportOptions` function to specify what data to be exported. Wherever you declare your button, just add the following to only export the visible data:

```
  buttons: [
    {
      extend: 'excel',
      exportOptions: {
        columns: ':visible'
      }
    }
   ]
```

This is an example of the same behaviour, only with the print button:
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/columns.html